# User session undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I want to check if the user is admin, but when is not login I hit admin unedified:

```
var user = req.user;
        if (!user && user.admin) return res.redirect('/admin/login');
```

Comment: `!user && user.admin` doesn't make sense. You're checking for a property on an object only after ensuring that the object doesn't exist in the first place?

Comment: How would you check what a user is (admin or not) if it is not logged in?